# Codeigniter, Ajax: Pass the variable type date from view in controller

Tags: ajax, database, codeigniter, post

I would like to send variables by post method from view to controller using Ajax. My code doesn't work. Can someone help me?

My View: variables change with daterangepicker

```
var v_start_date = moment().subtract(7, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
var v_end_date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
...
//window.location.replace("<?php echo site_url('consum/ajax_excel');?>" + "/" + v_start_date + "/" + v_end_date);
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('consum/ajax_excel')?>",
    type: "POST",
    dataType : "JSON",
    data:  {
       start_date: v_start_date,
       end_date: v_end_date
    },
    success:function(data) {
    },
    error : function(data) {
    }
});

...
```

My Controller:

```
public function ajax_excel() {
    //$start_date = $this->uri->segment(5);
    //$end_date = $this->uri->segment(6);
    $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
    $end_date = $this->input->post('end_date');
    $this->load->library('excel');
    $mobiledata = $this->consum->excel_list($start_date,$end_date);
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

...
```

My Model:

```
public function excel_list($start_date,$end_date){
    $this->db->select(array('date','consumator','produs','pret','cantitate','total','stare','utilizator'));
    $this->db->from('consum as m');
    if($start_date !="") if ($end_date !="") {
        $this->db->where('date >=', $start_date);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $end_date);
    }
    $this->db->order_by("date", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My code doesn't work..Explain this.Do you getting any errors?

Comment: I didn't read the errors. with the segment method it works. i don't think it reads the variable when i send through ajax

Comment: Look into console for checking is any error happening there

Comment: `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
 }`

Comment: 200 and SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

Comment: Dig into that error .You will find the solution.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. It takes the variables in the controller but it seems to mix with the contents of the excel file. The controller function calls the PHPExcel library

Answer (score 0):

first print_r($_POST) in your controller in order to make sure nothing is misspelled or it's because of encoding or etc. if nothing gets printed check out your routes.php in config folder. if you force CI to route from specific routes you may need to define a new route.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply
I changed dataType : "text"

When I have the function in the controller
'public function ajax_excel() {
  $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
  $end_date = $this->input->post('end_date');
  print_r($_POST);
  print_r($start_date);
  print_r($end_date);
 }'

displays an array and separates the variables well.

Comment: but when I have the function in the controller
`
public function ajax_excel() {
  $start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
  $end_date = $this->input->post('end_date');
  $this->load->library('excel');
  $mobiledata = $this->consum->excel_list($start_date,$end_date);
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
 ...
   $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
   $objWriter->save('php://output');
   return NULL;
`
mix the variables with the contents of the excel file. It seems so. Can anything be done? Thanks a lot!

Comment: the function in the controller must export an excel file with the PHPExcel library